# How to turn EditText to editable text-file like NotePad

Tags: java, android, android-layout

**Hi**

My problem is, that when I have a blank screen with `ScrollView` and `EditText`.
I wanted my app to allow user to write what ever and where ever he/she wants, **BUT** when I ran the app, you were only allowed to type in the middle. (I stretched the EditText to cover the whole screen)

Here is my screen:

[image]

Here is the screen I should/need to have:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="onhar.personalnote.Writing_Table">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1000dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1000dp">



            </RelativeLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/plusicon" />

    <include layout="@layout/content_writing__table" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

***Is this possible?***

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: Check it now please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where position is an int:

```
editText1.setSelection(position);

editText1.setSelection(0); //You can set it as 0.
```

Answer (score 1):

In your XML you need `android:gravity="top|start"` on your EditText.

If you want to do it in Java code then it's: `myEditText.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.START);`

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText yourEt= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEt);
yourEt.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(yourEt, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

// You can set focus of edittext only. 
// Please share your code.
```

Comment: You need to change your layouts.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you should never use fixed height. And answer to your query is add this attribute `android:fillViewport="true"` to your `ScrollView`. Also add `android:gravity="top"` to you EditText.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:hint="Hello" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```